# Weird accuracy score in approximation sin

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I'm learning keras and trying to approximate sin. Everything seems fine, my loss decreases. But the problem is that accuracy doesn't change. Here is the code:

```
from tensorflow import keras
from keras.layers import Dense
import numpy as np

X = np.linspace(0,10,100)
y = np.sin(X)

model = keras.Sequential([
    Dense(100,input_shape=(1,), activation='linear',name='relu'),
    Dense(100,activation='relu', name='layer_2'),
    Dense(1,activation='tanh', name='layer_3')
])

model.compile(loss='mse',optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
history = model.fit(X,y,epochs=100, batch_size = 2,verbose=0,validation_split=0.2)
```

And here are the graphics which I got:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Accuracy is a classification metric, and it is meaningless in regression tasks, like this one.

Answer (score 1):

With `loss='mse'`, the accuracy is going to be weirded out since it is not a classification task. Normally when doing a regression task you do not put `metrics=['accuracy']`. I suggest to not worry about it, as your loss is decreasing.

Comment: Yeah, but the thing is it's not a classification problem. It's a sort of regression, that's why I'm using mse and accuracy

Comment: @EugeneKartashev pls read the answer more closely (which, frankly, could have been worded better).